# how to get ID of a Auto-populated combobox from a database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, insert, auto-increment

For example I have a database with 2 tables:

```
tblOrder              
OrderID <PK> Auto-Increment          
CustomerID <FK>       
Date    

tblCustomer   
CustomerID <PK> Auto-increment
CustomerName
```

Then I filled a `combobox` in an order form with `CustomerName`:

```
 query = "select * from database.tblCustomer"
        con.open
        dr = New MySqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            cmbSupplier.Items.Insert(dr.GetString("CustomerName")
        End While
```

I need to know how to get the `customerID` from the selected `customerName` so that I can insert it in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should retrieve only the fields needed and then assign the result of your query to the `DataSource` property of the combobox. Then you set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` property to the names of the relative columns

```
    query = "select CustomerID, CustomerName from database.tblCustomer"
    con.open
    dr = New MySqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader
    Dim dt = new DataTable()
    dt.Load(dr)
    cmbSupplier.DisplayMember = "CustomerName"
    cmbSupplier.ValueMember = "CustomerID"
    cmbSupplier.DataSource = dt
```

After this, retrieving the CustomerID is simply a matter of reading the SelectedValue property
(do not forget to check if there is something selected in the combo)

```
   if cmbSupplier.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim custID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbSupplier.SelectedValue)
   End If
```